# Is there a way to add a custom message to HTML5 camera permission infobar?

Tags: html, ionic-framework, webrtc

I need to add a description for the use my application do of the camera permission in HTML5 but I can't find access to the message in the browser permission infobar.

I don't have problem to get the permission! Just need to explain to my users why I request this permission.

It's an Ionic 5 application build as a PWA.

[image: screenshot of the permission infobar]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to alter this dialog.

A common pattern is that a website shows a message at first before actually triggering the prompt. It usually says something like "This page needs to access your camera because ...". Typically there is button saying something like "Allow camera access" which then triggers the browser prompt.